# How to set up reviewboard with Github repo?

Tags: github, review

I ran into several problems while setting up reviewboard.

1. if I select GitHub directly as hosting service, I always got 'bad credentials' when linking to github with a new account.
2. if I chose hosting service to 'None - Custom Repository', Repository type to 'Git', I don't know how to set the [**raw file url**](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.7/admin/configuration/repositories/#raw-file-urls)  for Github.

I failed to get it worked either way, any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a clone of the git repository on the host where your review board server is hosted. Say you make the clone of the git repo at `/home/username/repo/repository`.

Go to the .git directory in your repository home. In this case it would be `/home/username/repo/repository/.git` This is the directory you need to give in your repository settings in ReviewBoard admin portal. Note, one problem with doing it this way is you will have to manually refresh the git repository whenever somebody pushes any changes to it.

Another way would be to use cgit or gitweb. But this requires some setup on the git server side, which may not be possible if you are not maintaining the central git repo yourself.

I am currently using the first method of having git repos in ReviewBoard server and refreshing them automatically with a cron job.